# Latency in Spark streaming job Databricks which sources from an Azure Iot Hub

Tags: python, apache-spark, azure-databricks, spark-structured-streaming, azure-iot-hub

I have been using a Spark **streaming** job using **Python** on **Databricks** to load sources from an Azure **IotHub**. However I noticed, when we have a large number of received frames, the job comes long, so we have **latency** knowing that when we look at the metrics the CPU and memory are **not** used at 100% of their capacity.

Answer (score 2):

IoT Hub, similarly to EventHubs has its own [throughput limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-scaling#message-throughput) based on the provisioned capacity, so you can't read more than X MB/sec or N messages/sec.

Also, you need to remember that EventHubs connector maps EventHubs partitions 1:1 into Spark partitions, so if EventHubs/IoT Hub has fewer partitions than Spark cores, then not all cores are used. As alternative, you can consider using of Kafka connector to connect to EventHubs/IoT Hub as it allows to have more Spark partitions than partitions in EventHubs (see [minPartitions option in Kafka connector](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html))